# JQuery Conditional Events

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to have a conditional jquery event?

i.e.

```
if thisBox.is(clicked) or thatBox.is(clicked) {
   //do this
}
```

My example pertains to this piece of code:

```
$('.pdfClose').click(function(){
   $('.thePDF').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $('.pdfContainer').removeClass('pdfShown');
    });
});
```

So what I would like to have is

```
($('.pdfClose') || $('.pdfContainer')).click(function(){
   $('.thePDF').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        //$(this).hide();
        $('.pdfContainer').removeClass('pdfShown');
    });
});
```

Something like that, but I don't even know if it exists or what the proper syntax is.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this

```
$('.pdfClose, .pdfContainer').on('click', function(){
   var self = this;

   $('.thePDF').fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $(self).removeClass('pdfShown');
    });
});
```

you can use multiple selectors by separating them with a comma, and inside the event handler `this` would reference the current one.

Comment: it cannot be done directly using `.click()` only using `.on()`?

Comment: @metsales - both works just fine, but `on()` is the preferred way to add event handlers these days.

Comment: I'm curious as to why that is? is it because it follows closer to the Javascript syntax?

Comment: @metsales click() is just a shorthand for `.on('click',...)` that's all you should know about it. Anyway, i don't really understand what you are asking here

Comment: also, the first line you have `$('.pdfClose, .pdfContainer')` should all of the event handlers be in one set of quotes of each in its own : `$('.pdfClose', '.pdfContainer')`

Comment: A few jQuery versions ago you'd use all the different events, as in `click()`, `focus()`, `mouseenter()` etc. and live() or delegate() for dynamic elements. Then in jQuery 1.7 they decided to use on() for everything, as it's simpler, easier to remember, and more resembles the native syntax with `onclick`, `onmouseenter` etc.

Comment: @metsales no, here you are providing context: `$('.pdfClose', '.pdfContainer')`

Comment: ^^ what he said, comma between quotes is the context selector, something completely different.

Comment: @adeneo got a good link for that ^^? and if the site is using jQuery 1.6.4 should I stick to `click()` or would `on()` work?

Comment: You should upgrade to a newer version of jQuery, and if that's not an option, you would have to use `click()` as `on()` was added in 1.7.

Comment: @A.Wolff & adeneo thanks for all the help guys! Need to wait 1 min before accepting